# Do while with try catch JAVA validation

Tags: java

I'm having a trouble figuring out how to solve this issue when it just stops when I call this method when I input letters and other types. What is the problem with my code? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
public int selectOption(int maxRange, String sourceType) throws IOException
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            userInput = input.nextInt();

        }//end try
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            validInput=false;               
            input.next();

        }//end catch

        if (userInput<1 || userInput>maxRange)
        {
            MovieHouse.clearScreen();
            System.out.println("Select from the options only!");
            loadHeader();

            if(sourceType.equals("main"))
                MovieHouse.homeMenu();
            else if(sourceType.equals("movie menu"))
                loadMovieMenu();

        }//end if

    }while(userInput<1 || userInput>maxRange || validInput==false);

    return userInput;

}//end selectOption
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what is meaning of input.next();

Comment: why are you doing input.next() in the catch? And what exactly do you mean it just stops?

Comment: We need more information about what you're trying to achieve and what is wrong. For starters, I can see that you're not initializing or declaring variables in your method.

Comment: Shouldn't you move your if block to your try? Is it worth testing the value of userInput if an InputMismatchException was thrown?

Comment: Hi. My objective is to handle the exception and if the input of the user is not a number, it will run a loop to prompt the user to enter a correct number for the program to continue. I want to handle the exception while not ending the program. What would you suggest in this case?

Answer (score 1):

"input letters" - Does it mean normally the program take digits and you are providing char as input.

Not clear what is your issue.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Peeskillet - I can not comment on others post as I do not have adequate reputation. :)

Comment: @Peeskillet - Thanks!! But it says you need 50 reputation. I have 25. :). Its fine, I will achieve it. Thank you.